# View too large to fit into drawing cache on Webview inside scrollview

Tags: android, webview, scrollview

I am working on a scrollview that contain a webview, it works perfect on the 2.3, 4.1 , but when I try it on the 4.4 emulator, it show

```
  View too large to fit into drawing cache, needs 5744640 bytes, only 3932160 available
```

The webview is just blank.

And it is the layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:overScrollMode="never" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/newsTitle"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/last_update" />

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/newsContent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="@string/last_update" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/newsDate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/last_update" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I tried to use `mywebView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);` but it just return the same warning.

Also, I find the problem occur when the webpage is overscreen size , but when I show it , I find the layout of the web is slightly different, on 2.3 , 4.1 , it can simply start the new line if the word is exceed the page, however , in 4.4 it does not , so part of the word is out of the screen .

How to fix it? Thanks

Comment: I finally give up , as it is buggy in android, just make my background white and the webview background white, everything perfect then

Comment: Try largeHeap = "true"

in your <application> tag in manifest. It enables your app to use a little bit larger heap than the usual one(So that the cache size may be increased). It may help you. Just try and let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your help, still the same error

Comment: I have also tried setting the software layer on the webview for API >= 11, very buggy (some has flashing problem, some has not display anything (View too large problem))

Comment: Have you tried to set your own webviewclient to the webview. I used to set my own webviewclient and I didn't face anything like this in my case even I loaded a webview which is wider than my device width(exactly thrice as my screen).

Comment: Please refer these links for setting webviewclient to the webview
http://www.technotalkative.com/android-webviewclient-example/
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_webview_layout.htm

Comment: Thanks, is your webview on a scrollview? I suspect this is the root of the problem

Comment: Oops.. I used but that's not the wider one. I loaded the wider webpage in a seperate webview. Ok thanks for the clue. And I will check it within a scroll view and come back to you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52164/discussion-between-sripathi-and-user782104)

Comment: Thanks, it seems to avoid create a webview with transparent background is the best option

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My Suggestion is give layout height to webview so that it wont exceed the your specified height

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/webview1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dip" >

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/sampletxt"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

In your activity just include the below lines

```
 SampleTxt.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
                SampleTxt.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    SampleTxt.loadData("Your Text To show the Webview",
                        "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);
```

It will work fine. any doubts let me know

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use your own WebView client. In android we can use WebViewClient or WebChromeClient. Using this you would get better result that you want. Just try it and check.

Answer (score 0):

For WebViews in Android, you should start from the assumption that things are buggy. They shouldn't be, but as you discovered, if you make the background a flat color, it "resolves" the issue.

Having said that, it is still a good idea to keep in mind that you're dealing with a wide range of mobile devices with wildly different processing and memory allocations when you're coding for Android phones, so always be sure to *test on a real device*.

If you don't have at least 4 or 5 different physical Android devices that you can test on, then look around for services that allow you to use their devices to test remotely. Never believe that because you have tested something in an emulator, it will behave the same on a real device.